# Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic for Positive Rational Numbers and not just Integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

I'm using a picture because I want to reflect the book. I'm flustered. Why not introduce the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic  as Exercise 2.19,
for $\{$ positive rational numbers $\} \supseteq \mathbb{Z}>1$?  Why just $\mathbb{Z}>1$ first — and then make an exercise about it for $\{$ positive rational numbers $\}$ ?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) — Allowing negative exponents provides a canonical form for positive rational numbers.

Comment: a nonzero rational number is defined in terms of two integers with no common factors. a rational integer just means an integer

Comment: @DavidHolden Thanks. i fixed title

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ord}{\operatorname{ord}}$
Let $r$ be a non-zero rational number. Then, by definition, there exist integers $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, non-zero, such that $r = a/b$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic in $\mathbb Z$, we can write $$a = \pm\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{\ord_{p_i}(a)},$$
and
$$b = \pm \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{\ord_{p_i}(b)},$$
where $\{p_i\}$ is the set of all prime numbers in $\mathbb Z$ and $\ord_{p_i}(a),\ord_{p_i}(b) \in \mathbb N$ are zero for almost all indexes $i$ (except by a finite number). This decomposition is unique. So, if you define $\ord_{p_i}(r)=\ord_{p_i}(a)-\ord_{p_i}(b)$, then, since $r = a/b$, we have
$$ r = {\left(\pm\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{\ord_{p_i}(a)}\right) \over \left(\pm \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{\ord_{p_i}(b)}\right)} = \pm\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{\ord_{p_i}(r)},$$
where, now, $\ord_{p_i}(r) \in \mathbb Z$ is zero for almost all indexes. This shows the existence of prime factorization in $\mathbb Q$. If you are interested, verify this factorization is unique.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is too hard. What's $ord(p_i)$? Can you simplify please?

Comment: $\operatorname{ord}_{p_i}(a)$ is the exponent of $p_i$ that appears in the prime factorization of $a$.

Comment: thanks. and why is $ord_{p_i} = 0$  for almost all indexes i (except by a finite number) ? Can you please answer in your answer (not in comments)? Can you please move your comment overhead into your answer?